# How to add multiple Azure VMSS to one basic tier Azure load balancer?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

I am using VMSS with basic tier load balancer and public IP address. When I am doing application update, I want to create new VMSS to make sure it is not affecting the old VMSS. Now I am creating new VMSS with new IP and load balancer. However, I do not want the IP to change. Is there any way to create a new VMSS connecting to an existing basic tier load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple Azure VMSS to one Basic tier Azure load balancer.
Azure Basic load balancer only supports virtual machines in a single availability set or virtual machine scale set (this is a single VMSS).
Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/skus

However, Standard load balancer supports any virtual machines or virtual machine scale sets (multiple) in a single virtual network.
So, you can easily configure a VMSS with an existing Standard SKU load balancer using the Azure portal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/configure-vm-scale-set-portal

Comment: This make sense. Thank you so much!